# How to calculate the Kampé de Fériet function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, special-functions, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function

This is a continuation of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2977213/simplify-sum-l-0-infty-sum-r-0-infty-frac-gammalr-2q-gammalr-1).

The following is my original question in that post.

> **Question**: Is it possible to express 
>   $$\sum_{l=0}^\infty \sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(L+r-2q)}{\Gamma(L+r-1+2q)} \frac{\Gamma(L+r+l-1+2q)}{\Gamma(L+r+l+2)}\frac{r+1}{r+l+2}$$
>   in closed form independent of summations (possibly in terms of Gamma function)?

---

@G Cab managed to reduce the double summations above using [Kampé de Fériet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamp%C3%A9_de_F%C3%A9riet_function)

$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
 & S(L,q) = A\;\sum\limits_{r = 0}^\infty  {\sum\limits_{l = 0}^\infty  {{{3^{\,\overline {\,r + l\,} }
 \left( {c - d} \right)^{\,\overline {\,r + l\,} } } \over {4^{\,\overline {\,r + l\,} } c^{\,\overline {\,r + l\,} } }}{{3^{\,\overline {\,r\,} } 1^{\,\overline {\,l\,} }
 \left( {a - b} \right)^{\,\overline {\,r\,} } 1^{\,\overline {\,l\,} } 1^{\,\overline {\,r\,} } 1^{\,\overline {\,l\,} } }
 \over {2^{\,\overline {\,r\,} } 1^{\,\overline {\,l\,} } a^{\,\overline {\,r\,} } 1^{\,\overline {\,l\,} } }}{{x^{\,r} }
 \over {r!}}{{y^{\,l} } \over {l!}}} }   =   \cr 
  &  = F\left( {\matrix{   2  \cr    3  \cr    2  \cr    2  \cr 
 } \,\left| {\,\matrix{
   {3,\left( {c - d} \right)}  \cr 
   {3,\,1\;;\;\left( {a - b} \right),1\;;\;\;1,1}  \cr 
   {4,c}  \cr 
   {2,\,1\;;\;a,1}  \cr 
 } \,} \right|x,y} \right)\quad \quad \left| {\;x = y = 1} \right. \cr} 
}$$

where $r,l,L\geq 1$ are integers and $q\in [0,1]$ is a real number.

The final answer should be similar to the form

$$1 - \frac{2q^2}{(1-2q)^2} - \frac{2\pi q(1-q)}{(1-2q)(3-4q)} \cot(2\pi q).$$

---

Here comes my question for this post.

> **Question**: How to calculate the Kampé de Fériet function to get answer above?

---

Based on @Nikos Bagis in that post, Mathematica 10 gives something involving gamma functions, cotangent and some [generalized hypergeometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function#Notation).

---

UPDATED: 08/11/18 @Nikos Bagis compuated a closed form for the double summations above.

$$
F_1(L,q,x):=\sum^{\infty}_{l=0}\sum^{\infty}_{r=0}\frac{\Gamma(L+r-2q)\Gamma(L+r+l-1+2q)}{\Gamma(L+r-1+2q)\Gamma(L+r+l+2)}x^lx^r.
$$
Then
$$
F_1(L,q,x)=-\frac{\Gamma(L-2q)(L-2q-1)}{4q-2}{}\frac{1}{\Gamma(L+2)} {}_2F_1(1,L-2q;L+2;x)+
$$
$$
\frac{(L+2q-2)\Gamma(L-2q)}{4q-2} \frac{1}{\Gamma(L+2)} {}_2F_1\left(1,L+2q-1;L+2;x\right)-
$$
$$
-\frac{\Gamma(L-2q)}{4q-2} \frac{1}{\Gamma(L-+)} {}_2F_1\left(2,L-2q;L+2;x\right),
$$
where 
$$
pF_q\left(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_p;b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_q;z\right):=
$$
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(a_1)_n (a_2)_n...(a_p)_n}{(b_1)_n (b_2)_n...(b_p)_n}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
is the generalized hypergeometric function.

Now my question is

> How to show that 
>    $$\sum^{\infty}_{l=0}\sum^{\infty}_{r=0}\frac{\Gamma(L+r-2q)\Gamma(L+r+l-1+2q)}{\Gamma(L+r-1+2q)\Gamma(L+r+l+2)}x^lx^r = $$
>   $$
> F_1(L,q,x)=-\frac{\Gamma(L-2q)(L-2q-1)}{4q-2}{}\frac{1}{\Gamma(L+2)} {}_2F_1(1,L-2q;L+2;x)+
> $$
>   $$
> \frac{(L+2q-2)\Gamma(L-2q)}{4q-2} \frac{1}{\Gamma(L+2)} {}_2F_1\left(1,L+2q-1;L+2;x\right)-
> $$
>   $$
> -\frac{\Gamma(L-2q)}{4q-2} \frac{1}{\Gamma(L-+)} {}_2F_1\left(2,L-2q;L+2;x\right)
> $$
>   and 
>   $$
> F_2(L,q,x)=
> $$
>   $$
> =\frac{x\Gamma(L-2q+1)(2+L-6q-4Lq+8q^2)}{2(2q-1)(4q-3)\Gamma(L+3)}{}_2F_1\left(2,L-2q+1;L+3;x\right)-
> $$
>   $$
> -\frac{\Gamma(L-2q+1)(L+2q-2)}{2(2q-1)(4q-3)\Gamma(L+2)}{}_2F_1(1,L-2q;L+2;x)+
> $$
>   $$
> +\frac{\Gamma(L-2q+1)(L+2q-2)}{2(2q-1)(4q-3)\Gamma(L+2)}{}_2F_1(1,L+2q-1;L+2;x)-
> $$
>   $$
> -x\frac{\Gamma(L-2q+1)}{(4q-3)\Gamma(L+3)} {}_3F_2\left(2,2,L-2q+1;1,L+3;x\right).
> $$
>   where 
>   $$
> F_2(L,q,x):=\sum^{\infty}_{l=0}\sum^{\infty}_{r=0}\frac{\Gamma(L+r-2q) \Gamma(L+r+l-1+2q)}{\Gamma(L+r-1+2q) \Gamma(L+r+l+2)}rx^lx^r?
> $$

Comment: I guess $q=0$ is not allowed as the series is only convergent for $q>0$.

Comment: I think I have answer this question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2977213/simplify-sum-l-0-infty-sum-r-0-infty-frac-gammalr-2q-gammalr-1

Comment: @Diger yes you are right. We don't allow $q=0$.

Comment: @NikosBagis Nikos, would you know the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4728274/4781) about the sextic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is another approach where I first introduce
\begin{align}
\Gamma(L+r-2q) &= \int_0^\infty t_1^{L+r-2q-1} \, e^{-t_1} \, {\rm d}t_1 \\
\Gamma(L+r+l+2q-1) &= \int_0^\infty t_2^{L+r+l+2q-2} \, e^{-t_2} \, {\rm
d}t_2 \\
r+1 &= \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t_3} \, t_3^{r+1} \bigg|_{t_3=1^{-}} \\
\frac{1}{r+l+2} &= \int_0^1 t_4^{r+l+1} \, {\rm d}t_4 \\ \frac{1}{\Gamma(L+r+l+2)} &= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-\infty}^{0^+} t_5^{-(L+r+l+2)} \, e^{t_5} \, {\rm d}t_5 \\ \frac{1}{\Gamma(L+r+2q-1)} &= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-\infty}^{0^+} t_6^{-(L+r+2q-1)} \, e^{t_6} \, {\rm d}t_6 \end{align}
to avoid going into the details of hypergeometric functions $_pF_q$. In the last two expressions the bounds refer to Hankel's contour starting at $-\infty$ encircling $0$ once in positive direction and going back to $-\infty$.
These contours can be deformed to encircle the entire complex plane in a big circle as there is no other singularity than $0$.

Then without writing the integrals and derivatives and interchanging integration and summation order at will the summation essentially becomes two geometric series $$ \frac{1}{(2\pi i)^2} \, {\frac {{{t_1}}^{L-2q-1}\,{{ t_2}}^{L+2q-2}\, t_3 \, t_4 \,{{t_5}}^{-L}\,{{t_6}}^{-L-2q+2}\,{{\rm
e}^{-{t_1}-{t_2}+{t_5}+{t_6}}}}{ \left( {t_2}{t_4}-{t_5} \right)
  \left( {t_1}{t_2}{t_3}{t_4}-{t_5}{t_6} \right) }} \, .
$$

The procedure now is clear: We carry out the integrals in an appropriate order starting with $t_5$ since $L$ is a positive integer and the integrand is thus holomorph in $t_5$ so we can apply the residue theorem which yields 3 terms \begin{align}
I_1 &= \frac{ {{t_1}}^{L-2q-1}\,{{t_2}}^{L+2q-2} \, t_3 \, t_4 \, {{t_6}}^{-L-2q+1}\,{\rm e}^{-{t_1}-{t_2}+{t_6}} }{2\pi i} \, \frac{1}{(L-1)!} \, \frac{{\rm d}^{L-1}}{{\rm d}t_5^{L-1}} \frac{{\rm e}^{t_5}}{\left( {t_2}{t_4} - {t_5} \right)  \left( \frac{{t_1}{t_2}{t_3}{t_4}}{{t_6}} - {t_5} \right) } \Bigg|_{t_5=0} \\ &= \frac{ {{t_1}}^{L-2q-2}\,{{t_2}}^{L+2q-3} \, {{t_6}}^{-L-2q+2}\,{\rm e}^{-{t_1}-{t_2}+{t_6}} }{2\pi i} \, \sum_{k=0}^{L-1} \frac{1}{\Gamma(L-k)}  \frac{1}{(t_2t_4)^{k+1}} \sum_{l=0}^k \left( \frac{t_6}{t_1t_3} \right)^l \\ &= \frac{ {{t_1}}^{L-2q-2}\,{{t_2}}^{L+2q-3} \, {{t_6}}^{-L-2q+2}\,{\rm e}^{-{t_1}-{t_2}+{t_6}} }{2\pi i} \, \sum_{k=0}^{L-1} \frac{1}{\Gamma(L-k)}  \frac{1}{(t_2t_4)^{k+1}} \frac{\left( \frac{t_6}{t_1t_3} \right)^{k+1}-1}{\frac{t_6}{t_1t_3}-1} \\
I_2 &= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \, {\frac {{{t_1}}^{L-2q-1} \, {{t_2}}^{2q-3} \,
t_3 \, {{t_4}}^{-L} \, {{t_6}}^{-L-2q+2}\,{{\rm e}^{-{t_2}(1-{t_4})-{t_1}+{t_6}}}}{{t_6} - {t_1}{t_3}}} \\
I_3 &= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \, { \frac {{{t_1}}^{-2q-1} \, {{t_2}}^{2q-3} \, t_3^{-L+1} \, t_4^{-L} \, {{t_6}}^{-2q+2}}{{t_1}{t_3}-{t_6}} \, {{\rm e}^{{-t_2\left(1-\frac{{t_1}{t_3}{t_4}}{t_6}\right)-{t_1}+t_6}}} } \, .
\end{align}
The best next step is to do the $t_2$ integral which leads to a set of $\Gamma$-functions after we substitute $$
\tau_2=t_2(1-t_4) \\
\tau_3=t_2\left(1-\frac{t_1t_3t_4}{t_6}\right)
$$
in $I_2$ and $I_3$ respectively and so
\begin{align}
I_1 &= \frac{ {{t_1}}^{L-2q-2}\, {{t_6}}^{-L-2q+2}\,{\rm e}^{-{t_1}+{t_6}} }{2\pi i} \, \sum_{k=0}^{L-1} \sum_{l=0}^k \frac{\Gamma(L+2q-3-k)}{\Gamma(L-k)}  \frac{1}{t_4^{k+1}} \left( \frac{t_6}{t_1t_3} \right)^l \\
I_2 &= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \, \frac {t_1^{L-2q-1} \,{t_3}\,\left( 1-{t_4} \right)^{2-2q} \, {t_4}^{-L} \,t_6^{-L-2q+2} \, {\rm e}^{-{t_1}+{t_6}} \, \Gamma \left( 2q-2 \right) }{{t_6}-{t_1}{t_3}} \\
I_3 &= -\frac{1}{2\pi i} \, \frac {{{t_1}}^{-2q-1} \, {{t_3}}^{-L+1} \, {{t_4}}^{-L} \, \left( {t_6}-{t_1}{t_3}{t_4} \right)^{2-2q} \, {\rm e}^{-t_1+t_6} \Gamma \left(2q-2 \right) }{{t_6}-{t_1}{t_3}} \, .
\end{align}
Now $t_6 = R\,{\rm e}^{i\phi}$ for $R\rightarrow \infty$ and $\phi \in (0,2\pi)$ and then using for $I_1,I_2$ and $I_3$
\begin{align}
\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=R} \frac{(z-c)^{-b} \, {\rm e}^z}{z-a} \, {\rm d}z &= \frac{(a-c)^{-b} \, {\rm e}^a \, \gamma(b,a-c)}{\Gamma(b)} \\ &= \frac{(a-c)^{-b} \, {\rm e}^a \left\{\Gamma(b)-\Gamma(b,a-c)\right\}}{\Gamma(b)} \\
\Rightarrow \qquad \lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=R} z^{-b-1} \, {\rm e}^z \, {\rm d}z &= \lim_{a\rightarrow 0} \lim_{c\rightarrow 0} \frac{(a-c)^{-b} \, {\rm e}^a \, \gamma(b,a-c)}{\Gamma(b)} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(b+1)}
\end{align}
which yields
\begin{align}
I_1 &= { {\rm e}^{-{t_1}} } \, \sum_{k=0}^{L-1} \sum_{l=0}^k \frac{\Gamma(L+2q-3-k)}{\Gamma(L-k)} \frac{ t_1^{L-2q-2-l} \, t_3^{-l} \, t_4^{-k-1} }{\Gamma(L+2q-2-l)}  \\
I_2 &= { t_1^{-4q+1} \,{t_3}^{-L-2q+3} \, {t_4}^{-L} \, \left( 1-{t_4} \right)^{2-2q} \, {\rm e}^{-{t_1}(1-{t_3})} \,  \Gamma \left( 2q-2 \right) } \left\{1 - \frac{\Gamma(L+2q-2,t_1t_3)}{\Gamma(L+2q-2)}\right\} \\
I_3 &= - {{{t_1}}^{-4q+1} \, {{t_3}}^{-L-2q+3} \, {{t_4}}^{-L} \, \left( 1-{t_4} \right)^{2-2q} \, {\rm e}^{-t_1(1-t_3)} } \left\{ \Gamma\left(2q-2\right) - \Gamma\left(2q-2,t_1t_3(1-t_4)\right) \right\} \, .
\end{align}
The first terms of $I_2$ and $I_3$ cancel when adding up, so we are not going to write them down anymore. Doing the $t_3$ derivative and setting $t_3=1$ the exponential functions occurring together with the incomplete Gamma functions vanish
\begin{align}
I_1 &= -{ {\rm e}^{-{t_1}} } \, \sum_{k=0}^{L-1} \sum_{l=0}^k \frac{l \, \Gamma(L+2q-3-k)}{\Gamma(L-k)} \frac{ t_1^{L-2q-2-l} \, t_4^{-k-1} }{\Gamma(L+2q-2-l)}  \\
I_2 &= - \frac{ t_1^{-4q+1}  \, {t_4}^{-L} \, \left( 1-{t_4} \right)^{2-2q} \, \Gamma \left( 2q-2 \right) }{\Gamma(L+2q-2)} \Big\{ (-L-2q+3) \, {\Gamma(L+2q-2,t_1)} \\ &\quad + t_1 \, {\Gamma(L+2q-2,t_1)} - t_1^{L+2q-2} \, {\rm e}^{-t_1} \Big\} \\
I_3 &= { {{t_1}}^{-4q+1} \, {{t_4}}^{-L} \, \left( 1-{t_4} \right)^{2-2q} } \Big\{ (-L-2q+3) \, \Gamma\left(2q-2,t_1(1-t_4)\right) \\ &\quad + t_1 \, \Gamma\left(2q-2,t_1(1-t_4)\right) - t_1^{2q-2} \left(1-t_4\right)^{2q-2} \, {\rm e}^{-t_1(1-t_4)} \Big\} \, .
\end{align}
We now use
$$
\int_0^\infty t^a \, \Gamma(s,t) \, {\rm d}t = \frac{\Gamma(s+a+1)}{a+1}
$$
which all $t_1$ integrals can be brought to after a possible substitution $t=t_1(1-t_4)$ ending up at
\begin{align}
I_1 &= - \sum_{k=0}^{L-1} \sum_{l=0}^k \frac{l \, \Gamma(L+2q-3-k)}{\Gamma(L-k)} \frac{ \Gamma(L-2q-1-l) \, t_4^{-k-1} }{\Gamma(L+2q-2-l)}  \\
I_2 &= - \frac{ {t_4}^{-L} \, \left( 1-{t_4} \right)^{2-2q} \, \Gamma \left( 2q-2 \right) }{\Gamma(L+2q-2)} \left\{ (-L-2q+3) \, \frac{\Gamma(L-2q)}{-4q+2} + \frac{\Gamma(L-2q+1)}{-4q+3} - \Gamma(L-2q) \right\} \\
&= {\frac { {{t_4}}^{-L} \left( 1-{t_4} \right)^{2-2q} \, \Gamma \left( 2q-2 \right) \Gamma \left( L-2q \right) }{2 \left( 2q-1 \right)  \left( 4q-3 \right) \Gamma \left( L+2q-3 \right) }} \\
I_3 &= { {{t_4}}^{-L} } \left\{ (-L-2q+3) \, \left( 1-{t_4} \right)^{2q} \, \frac{\Gamma\left(-2q\right)}{-4q+2} + \left( 1-{t_4} \right)^{2q-1} \, \frac{\Gamma\left(-2q+1\right)}{-4q+3} - \left(1-t_4\right)^{2q} \, \Gamma(-2q) \right\} \\
&= -{\frac {4\,{{t_4}}^{-L} \left( 1-{t_4} \right)^{2q-1}\Gamma\left(-2q \right) \left\{  \left( q-\frac{3}{4} \right)  \left( L-2q-1 \right) {t_4} + \left( -L+\frac{1}{2} \right) q+\frac{3(L-1)}{4} \right\} }{2(2q-1)(4q-3)}} \, .
\end{align}
The remaining $t_4$ integral is divergent, but can be made finite by analytic continuation using Beta-function regularization
$$
\int_0^1 t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1} \, {\rm d} t = \frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}
$$
giving
\begin{align}
I_1 &= \sum_{k=0}^{L-1} \sum_{l=0}^k \frac{\Gamma(L+2q-3-k)}{\Gamma(L-k)} \frac{ \Gamma(L-2q-1-l) }{\Gamma(L+2q-2-l)} \, \frac{l}{k}  \\
I_2 &= -{\frac {\sin \left(\pi L + 2\pi q\right) \Gamma\left( -L+1 \right) \Gamma \left( L-2q \right) }{ 2 \left( 2q-1 \right) \left( 4q-3 \right) \sin \left( 2\pi q \right) }} \\
I_3 &=  -{\frac {\pi\,\Gamma \left( -L+1 \right) }{ 2 \left( 2q-1 \right) \left( 4q-3 \right)  \Gamma \left( 2q-L+1 \right) \sin \left( 2\pi q \right) }}  \, .
\end{align}
There however remains an ambiguity if $k=0$ when $l/k=0/0$ is undefined.

For $L$ integer these expressions are not defined as well, but only the sum of $I_2$ and $I_3$ which is
\begin{align}
I_2 + I_3 &= -{\frac {\sin \left( \pi L \right)  \Gamma \left( -L+1 \right) \Gamma \left( L-2q \right) \cot\left(2\pi q\right) }{ \left( 2q-1 \right) \left( 4q-3 \right) }} \\
&= -{\frac {\pi \,  \cot\left(2\pi q\right) \, \Gamma \left( L-2q \right) }{  \left( 2q-1 \right) \left( 4q-3 \right) \Gamma\left(L\right) }} \, .
\end{align}
The final result would then be
$$
I_1 + I_2 + I_3 \, .
$$

---

**edit:** The $k=0$ term can actually be obtained by analytic continuation. We calculate $$\sum_{l=0}^k \frac{\Gamma(\alpha-l)}{\Gamma(\beta-l)} \, x^l$$ in terms of hypergeometric functions $_2F_1$. Then we derive with respect to $x$ (the result being $_2F_1$ again) and evaluate at $x=1$. Using the connection formula we can express this in terms of $\Gamma$-functions. The result is
$$
{\frac {\Gamma \left( 1+\alpha \right) \Gamma \left( \beta-k-1
 \right) +\Gamma \left( \beta-1 \right) \Gamma \left( \alpha-k
 \right)  \left\{  \left( -1-k \right) \alpha+k \left( \beta-1 \right) 
 \right\} }{ \left( -2-\alpha+\beta \right)  \left( \beta-1-\alpha
 \right) \Gamma \left( \beta-1 \right) \Gamma \left( \beta-k-1
 \right) }}
$$
or with $\alpha=L-2q-1$, $\beta=L+2q-2$ and the remaining three factors of the $k$ sum
$$
{\frac { \Gamma \left( L-2\,q-1-k \right) }{\Gamma \left( L-k \right) \left( 4\,q-3 \right) }} \\ 
+ {\frac {\Gamma \left( L-2\,q \right) \Gamma \left( L+
2\,q-3-k \right) }{2 \, \Gamma \left( L-k \right) k \left( 2\,q-1 \right) 
 \left( 4\,q-3 \right) \Gamma \left( L+2\,q-3 \right) }} \\
+ {\frac { \left( -L+2\,q+1 \right) \Gamma \left( L-2\,q-1-k \right) }{2 \, \Gamma \left( L-k \right) k \left( 2\,q-1 \right)  \left( 4\,q-3 \right) }} \tag{1}
$$
which is finite for $k=0$ and any $q\in(0,1)$. The lengthy analysis of the limit $k=0$ yields
$$
\frac{\Gamma(L-2q)}{2 \, \Gamma(L) (2q-1) (4q-3)} \left\{ \Psi(L-2q) - \Psi(L+2q) \right\} \\
+ \frac{\Gamma(L-2q-1)}{2 \, \Gamma(L) (2q-1) (4q-3) (L+2q-1) (L+2q-2) (L+2q-3)} \Big\{ 32q^4 + (48L-144)q^3 \\ 
+ (24L^2-144L+196)q^2 + (4L^3-36L^2+104L - 88)q + 3L^2 - 10L + 7 \Big\} \, .
$$

We can use the above result (1) to symbolically carry out the $k$ sum from $1$ to $L-1$ the result being
$$
-{\frac {\Gamma \left( L-2\,q-1 \right) }{2 \, q \left( 4\,q-3
 \right) \Gamma \left( L-1 \right) }}+{\frac { \left\{ \Psi
 \left( L+2\,q-3 \right) -\Psi \left( 2\,q-2 \right)  \right\} \Gamma
 \left( L-2\,q \right) }{ 2 \left( 2\,q-1 \right)  \left( 4\,q-3
 \right) \Gamma \left( L \right) }}-{\frac { \left\{ \Psi \left( L
-2\,q-1 \right) - \Psi \left( -2\,q \right)  \right\} \Gamma \left( L-2
\,q \right) }{ 2 \left( 2\,q-1 \right)  \left( 4\,q-3 \right) \Gamma
 \left( L \right) }} \, .
$$

Finally adding up the previous two expressions and $I_2+I_3$ after simplifying we get

\begin{align} \bbox[lightyellow] {   \sum_{l=0}^\infty \sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(L+r-2q)}{\Gamma(L+r-1+2q)} \frac{\Gamma(L+r+l-1+2q)}{\Gamma(L+r+l+2)}\frac{r+1}{r+l+2} \\ 
= -{ \frac {\pi\,\cot \left( 2\,\pi\,q \right) \Gamma \left( L-2\,q
 \right) }{ 2 \left( 2\,q - 1 \right)  \left( 4\,q-3 \right) \Gamma
 \left( L \right) } } - { \frac { \left( 2\,{q}^{2}-4\,q+1 \right) 
\Gamma \left( L-2\,q \right) }{ 4 \left( 2\,q - 1\right) ^{2} q \left( q-1 \right) \Gamma \left( L \right) } }
 \, .  } \end{align}

---

**Concerning your follow up question:**

I don't have a solution, but wanted to make aware of the following procedure.

Assuming we know how to evaluate the $l$ sum, then there is the series
\begin{align}
&\sum_{r=0}^\infty \sum_{l=0}^\infty {\frac {\Gamma \left( L+r-2\,q \right) \Gamma \left( L+r+l-1+2\,q \right)}{\Gamma \left( L+r-1+2\,q \right) \Gamma
 \left( L+r+l+2 \right) } \,  {x}^{r}{y}^{l}} \\
=&\sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac {\Gamma \left( L+r-2\,q \right)}{\Gamma \left( L+r+2
 \right)} \, {\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(1,L+r-1+2\,q;\,L+r+2;\,y)} \, {x}^{r} \, . \tag{2}
\end{align}
You can either use the conventional integral representation to carry out the sum or use the following two identities (cf. https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.6)
\begin{align}
{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(a,b;\,c;\,z)} &= \frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(d)\Gamma(c-d)} \int_0^1 {\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(a,b;\,d;\,zt)} \, t^{d-1} (1-t)^{c-d-1} \, {\rm d}t \tag{3} \\
{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(a,b;\,c;\,z)} &= \frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(d)\Gamma(c-d)} \int_0^1 \frac{t^{d-1}(1-t)^{c-d-1}}{(1-zt)^{a+b-\lambda}} \, {\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(\lambda-a,\lambda-b;\,d;\,zt)} \, {\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}\left(a+b-\lambda,\lambda-d;\,c-d;\,\frac{(1-t)z}{1-zt}\right)} \, {\rm d}t \tag{4}
\end{align}
where in each expression $d$ and $d,\lambda$ are arbitrary constants at our free disposal.

For example if we plug (3) in (2) and choose $d=1$ the hypergeometric function can be evaluated by
$$
{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(1,b;\,1;\,z)} = (1-z)^{-b}
$$
and (2) becomes
$$
\int_0^1 (1-yt)^{1-L-2q} \, (1-t)^L \sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(L+r-2q)}{\Gamma(L+r+1)} \, \left( \frac{(1-t)x}{1-yt} \right)^r \, {\rm d}t \\
= \frac{\Gamma(L-2q)}{\Gamma(L+1)} \int_0^1 \frac{(1-t)^L}{(1-yt)^{L+2q-1}} \, {\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}\left(1,L-2q;\,L+1;\,\frac{(1-t)x}{1-yt}\right)} \, {\rm d}t \, . \tag{4.1}
$$
Substituting $s=\frac{1-t}{1-yt}$ reveals
$$
(1-y)^{2-2q} \, \frac{\Gamma(L-2q)}{\Gamma(L+1)} \int_0^1 \frac{s^L}{(1-ys)^{3-2q}} \, {\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}\left(1,L-2q;\,L+1;\,xs\right)} \, {\rm d}s \tag{4.2}
$$
so for $x=y$ only in the special case $q=3/4$ the integrand can be brought to (4) for a special choice of the parameters i.e. we first need to choosse $d=L+1$ and $c=L+2$ and $a+b-\lambda=3-2q$. Since $\lambda-a=1$ and $\lambda-b=L-2q$ we have $a=3-4q+L$ and $b=4-2q$ with $\lambda=4-4q+L$. Unfortunately the second hypergeometric function is unity only in the case $\lambda=d$ so for $3-4q=0$. Maybe this can be generalized by considering certain linear combinations; just saying.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach comes from expressing the sums in $(s,r)$ and then managing the resulting partial sum.

*1) the sum $F_1$*

Starting from your first question, we write it as
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & F_{\,1} (L,q,x) = \sum\limits_{r = 0}^\infty  {\sum\limits_{l = 0}^\infty
  {{{\Gamma (L + r - 2q)} \over {\Gamma (L + r - 1 + 2q)}}{{\Gamma (L + r + l - 1 + 2q)} \over {\Gamma (L + r + l + 2)}}x^{\,l} x^{\,r} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{s = 0}^\infty  {{{\Gamma (L + s - 1 + 2q)}
 \over {\Gamma (L + s + 2)}}x^{\,s} } \sum\limits_{r = 0}^s {{{\Gamma (L + r - 2q)} \over {\Gamma (L + r - 1 + 2q)}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{s = 0}^\infty  {{{\Gamma (L - 1 + 2q)} \over {\Gamma (L + 2)}}{{\left( {L - 1 + 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } }
 \over {\left( {L + 2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } }}x^{\,s} } {{\Gamma \left( {L - 2q} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {L - 1 + 2q} \right)}}
 \sum\limits_{r = 0}^s {{{\left( {L - 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,r\,} } } \over {\left( {L - 1 + 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,r\,} } }}}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{\Gamma \left( {L - 2q} \right)} \over {\Gamma (L + 2)}}\sum\limits_{s = 0}^\infty  {{{\left( {L - 1 + 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } }
 \over {\left( {L + 2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } }}x^{\,s} } \sum\limits_{r = 0}^s {{{\left( {L - 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,r\,} } }
 \over {\left( {L - 1 + 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,r\,} } }}}  \cr} 
} \tag {1.0}$$

Let us consider the inner partial sum.
It is a *sum of hypergeometric terms* and to it we can apply the [Gosper's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gosper's_algorithm),
which I find to be well described and analyzed in the renowned book [Concrete Mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics).
In the following I am concisely developing the steps recommended in
the relevant *"Ch. 5.7 - Partial Hypergeometric Sums"*: please refer to that for further details.

So
 - we write the sum as
$$
S_P (L,q,s) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^s {{{\left( {L - 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } } \over {\left( {L - 1 + 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }}}
  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^s {t_{\,k} } 
$$
 - express the ratio of the summand as
$$
{{t_{\,k + 1} } \over {t_{\,k} }} = {{\left( {L - 2q + k} \right)} \over {\left( {L - 2 + 2q + k + 1} \right)}} = {{p(k + 1)} \over {p(k)}}{{q(k)} \over {r(k + 1)}}
$$
 - choose the three polynomials to be
$$
\left\{ \matrix{  p(k) = 1 \hfill \cr   q(k) = L - 2q + k \hfill \cr   r(k) = L - 2 + 2q + k \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
  - determine the polynomial $s(k)$ by solving
$$
p(k) = q(k)s(k + 1) - r(k)s(k)\quad  \Rightarrow \quad s(k) = {1 \over {4q - 2}}
$$
 - arrive to find the antidifference $T(k)$ of $t_k$ to be
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\left\{ \matrix{
  T(k + 1) - T(k) = t_{\,k}  \hfill \cr 
  T(k) = {{r(k)s(k)t(k)} \over {p(k)}} = {{L - 2 + 2q} \over {4q - 2}}{{\left( {L - 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }
 \over {\left( {L - 2 + 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }} \hfill \cr}  \right.
} \tag {1.1}$$
 - and conclude that
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & S_P (L,q,s) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^s {{{\left( {L - 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } } \over {\left( {L - 1 + 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }}}
  = T(s + 1) - T(0) =   \cr 
  &  = {{L - 2 + 2q} \over {2 - 4q}}\left( {{{\left( {L - 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s + 1\,} } } 
\over {\left( {L - 2 + 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s + 1\,} } }} - 1} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {{L - 2 + 2q} \over {2 - 4q}}\left( {{{\left( {L - 2q} \right)\left( {L + 1 - 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } }
 \over {\left( {L - 2 + 2q} \right)\left( {L - 1 + 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } }} - 1} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {{{L - 2q} \over {2 - 4q}}} \right){{\left( {L + 1 - 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } } \over {\left( {L - 1 + 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } }}
 - {{L - 2 + 2q} \over {2 - 4q}} \cr} 
} \tag {1.2}$$

Note that, although $T(k)$ has a pole at $q=1/2$, it cancels out in the difference $T(k+1)-T(k)=t_k$.

Upon inserting (1.2) back into (1.0), then it is just a matter of algebraic manipulation.

*2) the sum $F_2$*

Since  $F_2$ is same as $F_1$ with the inner sum being multiplicated by $r$, then this is rewritten as
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & S_P (L,q,s) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^s {{{\left( {L - 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } } \over {\left( {L - 1 + 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }}k}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^s {{{\left( {L - 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } } \over {\left( {L - 1 + 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }}k}
  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^s {{{\left( {L-2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k + 1\,} } } \over {\left( {L-1+2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k+1\,} } }}\left( {k+1} \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{\left( {L - 2q} \right)} \over {\left( {L - 1 + 2q} \right)}}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{s - 1} 
{{{\left( {L - 2q + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } } \over {\left( {L + 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }}\left( {k + 1} \right)}  \cr} 
} \tag {2.0}$$

Proceeding similarly to the above, the steps in summary being
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  p(k) = \left( {k + 1} \right) \hfill \cr 
  q(k) = \left( {L - \left( {2q - 1} \right) + k} \right) \hfill \cr 
  r(k) = \left( {L + \left( {2q - 1} \right) + k} \right) \hfill \cr}  \right.  \cr 
  & s(k) = {1 \over {3 - 4q}}\left( {k + {{L - 2 + 2q} \over {2\left( {2q - 1} \right)}}} \right) \cr} 
$$
we reach to
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & T(k) = {{r(k)s(k)t(k)} \over {p(k)}} =   \cr 
  &  = {{L - 1 + 2q} \over {3 - 4q}}\left( {k + {{L - 2 + 2q} \over {4q - 2}}} \right){{\left( {L + 1 - 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }
 \over {\left( {L - 1 + 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }} \cr} 
} \tag {2.1}$$

Thus
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & S_P (L,q,s) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^s {{{\left( {L - 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } } \over {\left( {L - 1 + 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }}k}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{\left( {L - 2q} \right)} \over {\left( {L - 1 + 2q} \right)}}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{s - 1} {{{\left( {L - 2q + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }
 \over {\left( {L + 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }}\left( {k + 1} \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{\left( {L - 2q} \right)} \over {3 - 4q}}\left( {\left( {s + {{L - 2 + 2q} \over {4q - 2}}} \right){{\left( {L + 1 - 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } }
 \over {\left( {L - 1 + 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } }} - \left( {{{L - 2 + 2q} \over {4q - 2}}} \right)} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {{\left( {L - 2q} \right)} \over {3 - 4q}}\left( {\left( {s + 1 + {{L - 2q} \over {4q - 2}}} \right){{\left( {L + 1 - 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } }
 \over {\left( {L - 1 + 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } }} - \left( {{{L - 2 + 2q} \over {4q - 2}}} \right)} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {{\left( {L - 2q} \right)} \over {3 - 4q}}\left( {{{2^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } \left( {L + 1 - 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } } \over {1^{\,\overline {\,s\,} }
 \left( {L - 1 + 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } }} + \left( {{{L - 2q} \over {4q - 2}}} \right){{\left( {L + 1 - 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } }
 \over {\left( {L - 1 + 2q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } }} - \left( {{{L - 2 + 2q} \over {4q - 2}}} \right)} \right) \cr} 
} \tag {2.2}$$

*3) Gosper's algorithm applied directly to the original sum*

The [Gosper's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gosper's_algorithm) can be applied as well
to your original sum given [in the precedent post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2977213), in reply to which
it was already expressed in closed form as a

> [Kampé de Fériet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamp%C3%A9_de_F%C3%A9riet_function) computed at $x=y=1$.

Following the same steps as above, we can now express it also as a linear combination of hypergeometric functions.

In fact, putting
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  \matrix{
   {a = L - 2 + 2q} \hfill & {b = \,4q} \hfill  \cr 
   {c = L} \hfill & {d = 3 - 2q\,} \hfill  \cr 
 }  \hfill \cr 
  A = {1 \over 2}\left( {c + 2} \right)^{\,\overline {\, - d\,} } \left( {a + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,1 - b\,} }
  = {1 \over 2}\left( {L + 2} \right)^{\,\overline {\, - 2 - 2q\,} }  \hfill \cr}  \right.  \cr 
  & S(L,q) = \sum\limits_{r = 0}^\infty  {\sum\limits_{l = 0}^\infty  {{{\Gamma (L + r - 2q)} \over {\Gamma (L + r - 1 + 2q)}}
{{\Gamma (L + r + l - 1 + 2q)} \over {\Gamma (L + r + l + 2)}}{{r + 1} \over {r + l + 2}}} }   \cr 
  &  = A\;\sum\limits_{s = 0}^\infty  {{{2^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } \left( {2 + c - d} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } }
 \over {3^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } \left( {2 + c} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } }} 
 \sum\limits_{r = 0}^s {{{2^{\,\overline {\,r\,} } \left( {a + 2 - b} \right)^{\,\overline {\,r\,} } }
 \over {1^{\,\overline {\,r\,} } \left( {a + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,r\,} } }}} }  \cr}
} \tag {3.0}$$

for the inner sum
$$
S_{\,p} (a,b,s) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^s {{{2^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } \left( {a + 2 - b} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } } \over {1^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } \left( {a + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }}} 
$$
we go through  steps similar to the above and reach to
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & S_{\,p} (a,b,s) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^s 
 {{{2^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } \left( {a + 2 - b} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } } \over {1^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } \left( {a + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }}}  =   \cr 
  &  = {a \over {3 - b}}\left( {\left( {s + 1 - {{a - 1} \over {2 - b}}} \right){{\left( {a + 2 - b} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s + 1\,} } }
 \over {a^{\,\overline {\,s + 1\,} } }} + {{a - 1} \over {2 - b}}} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {a \over {3 - b}}\left( {{{\left( {a + 2 - b} \right)2^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } \left( {a + 3 - b} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } }
 \over {a\;1^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } \left( {a + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } }} - \left( {{{a - 1} \over {2 - b}}} \right){{\left( {a + 2 - b} \right)
 \left( {a + 3 - b} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } } \over {a\left( {a + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } }} + {{a - 1} \over {2 - b}}} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {{\left( {a + 2 - b} \right)} \over {3 - b}}\left( {{{2^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } \left( {a + 3 - b} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } }
 \over {1^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } \left( {a + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } }} - \left( {{{a - 1} \over {2 - b}}} \right){{\left( {a + 3 - b} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } } 
 \over {\left( {a + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,s\,} } }} + {{a\left( {a - 1} \right)} \over {\left( {a + 2 - b} \right)\left( {2 - b} \right)}}} \right) \cr} 
} \tag {3.1}$$